# Java: Push Notifications sent but not received

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

So, I'm trying to communicate with APNS from java. I've found java-apns, javapns and pushy libraries. Java-apns seems to have the most adequate API.

Init:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String certificateFilePath = args[0]; // "/path/to/cert.p12"
    apnsService = APNS.newService()
        .withCert(certificateFilePath, Config.APNS_PROVIDER_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD)
        .withDelegate(new ApnsDelegate() {
            @Override
            public void messageSent(ApnsNotification apnsNotification, boolean b) {
                System.out.println("message sent");
            }

            @Override
            public void messageSendFailed(ApnsNotification apnsNotification, Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println("message failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionClosed(DeliveryError deliveryError, int i) {
                System.out.println("connection closed");
            }

            @Override
            public void cacheLengthExceeded(int i) {
                System.out.println("cache length exceeded");
            }

            @Override
            public void notificationsResent(int i) {
                System.out.println("notification resent");
            }
        })
        .withSandboxDestination()
        .build();

    ...

}
```

At this moment iOS app is launched on the device. Local and remote notifications are registered, device token is got and sent to the server.

Then some event happens and I'm sending notification:

```
static void sendMessage(List<String> tokens, String message) {
    String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody(message).build();
    apnsService.push(tokens, payload);
}
```

Each token is something like `"5fb58761f9...4e92465e12"`.

The only thing that ApnsDelegate says is "message sent", but nothing happens on the device. And I think that the message was really sent, because I've tried to send notification with corrupted token and in that case, I'm getting "message failed" and a throwable with the error that says about invalid token.

So, actually I can't even understand the origin of my problem.  But I feel it is in Java, because the iOS part is very simple in contrast with server side with all its HTTP/2-voodoo-stuff.

Comment: @Hiteshsurani, I'm testing on the device with iOS10, but my deployment target is 8.0

Comment: If an edit from a 12K user (such as @RadLexus) is not to your liking, it may be worth pinging them to ask about the purpose of the edit. In this case it was quite correct - we do not use [solved] title hacks, nor do we put solutions in answers. Always put them in an answer, which I have done for you below.

Comment: @halfer, I can't see any button or link or other control here to "ping" or notify or start chat with someone here.

Comment: @seelts: you just pinged me with the `@` symbol, that is what I meant. Note it has tab completion too.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for ask this question.

I have faced same issue when work with iOS 10.

If you have working with iOS 10 or above, Then it is compulsory to ON remote notification in capabilities.

Go to `-> Project setting -> capabilities -> Enable Push Notifications.`

Go to -> `Project setting ->`capabilities`-> Background Mode -> Enable Remote Notification and VoIp`

**UPDATE:**

If you want to file the exact solution then check locally as follow.

Download `simplepush.php` from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5I4WIvp39a1SnhOLWh4dWdPczA)

Save your `.pem` file in same directory.

Replace your .pem file name and `simplepush.php`

Open terminal

Goto your simplepush.php directory.

Execute below command

```
php simplepush.php
```

If you have receive push then need to check from `java` end otherwise check into iOS end

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*:

I have solved it, it was my stupid mistake! The app was in foreground when I was expecting to see notifications. After I've closed it, notifications started to appear.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the notifications are not 'shown' by iOS if your app is in the foreground. HOWEVER, the notification event does happen and if you have the right method in your AppDelegate, iOS will give you the notification payload for your app to process. You could then do something in the background OR you could display your own UI (like showing a balloon with a number badge inside your app, for example).

See the [Apple doc for didReceiveRemoteNotification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application)

Comment: In my case `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called when app is in foreground

Comment: There are actually two forms of disReceiveRemoteNotification. One has more parameters than the other (a fetch completion handler). For iOS10 this is the version you have to support and it should get called on all notifications even in the foreground. However, you might still have to implement the other form depending on what SDK you are using to build. Make sure you implement both and check to see if one is firing. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application

Comment: I've tested with both forms